# How to add a bottom layer to an existing object Graphics (System.Drawing namespace)

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox, system.drawing

I have a Windows Form application developed in C# with Net Framework 4.8.

In this app I have a PictureBox control that shows an image. I can rotate the image in the PictureBox but after rotation in the background I can see BLACK color in the space where was the image.

Like this:

[image]

I want to change this color and I was thinking to add a bottom layer of the color that I want and that will not rotate.

**UPDATE**
I'm doing rotation with this code:

```
public static Bitmap RotateImageN(Bitmap b, float angle)
        {
            //Create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image.
            Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
            //Make a graphics object from the empty bitmap.
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
            
            //move rotation point to center of image.
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
            //Rotate.        
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            //Move image back.
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);

            g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, b.Width, b.Height); 
            return returnBitmap;
        }
```

Is it possible? How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's possible. How are you doing the rotation currently? Did you try `pictureBox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);`

Comment: This doesn't work @sorifiend I'll edit my question to explain how I'm doing rotation.

Comment: Before drawing the rotated image you can do a `g.Clear(colorOfYourChoice)`   - (Btw: The black is not where the image was but where it wasn't ;) - Also This is not a new layer but it simply clears the original backcolor, which by default a transparent black..

Comment: Yes @TaW sorry for my explanation. Your solution works! But if I want to add a bottom layer what should I do? (If you rite your solution in the answer I'll accept it)

Comment: I don't write answers here any longer but you can self-answer if you want. Actually this should be a duplicate, but I didn't find it right away. - As for layers: In a Bitmap there can only be one layer. To get more you need to stack Bitmaps, which you could draw on top of each other or display in stacked (ie __nested__) controls.

Comment: @dr. LOL, I'll have to think about these ;-)